# How to get app screen shot

Tags: c#, uwp

In the SL App, I can use:

```
var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(uiElementForViewControl, new TranslateTransform());
```

But in UWP, how do I do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RenderTargetBitmap to render a UIElement (such as your page) similar to how your snippet uses WriteableBitmap, then use a BitmapEncoder to encode the RenderTargetBitmap's pixels to a jpg or png to save out.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt244351.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
    private async Task SaveVisualElementToFile(FrameworkElement element, StorageFile file)
    {
        var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
        await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(element);
        var pixels = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();

        using (var fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, fileStream);
            encoder.SetPixelData(
                BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, 
                BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, 
                (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth,
                (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight,
                DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
                DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
                pixels.ToArray());
            await encoder.FlushAsync();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With `Control.DrawToBitmap` you can capture a Form, which is the "app" you are looking for.

Comment: That really is unfortunate. I myself believe having it used once on a Windows Forms application many years ago. I googled the function and I indeed see it doesn't work for everything and there are many approaches. I will however not post them as Rob has a good answer that helped the OP.